# RISCV instructions

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am new to riscv and I am confused between la and lw.

I know that `la` stands for load address and `lw` stands for load word. If address of **VAL** is `0x100` and data value of **VAL** is `0x11` should **x3** stores `0x100` and **x4** stores 0x11?

```
la x7, VAL
sw  x3, 0(x7)
lw  x4, VAL
bne x4, x3
```

Answer (score 6):

`la t0, SYMBOL` is an assembler pesudo instruction that puts the address of `SYMBOL` into `t0`.  Depending on the addressing mode, it expands to something like

```
lui t0, SYMBOL[31:12]
addi t0, t0, SYMBOL[11:0]
```

where `SYMBOL[31:12]` is the high bits of `SYMBOL`, and `SYMBOL[11:0]` is the low bits of `SYMBOL` -- these aren't valid assembler syntax, and there's some tricks to play with sign extension to get this exactly correct.

`lw t0, SYMBOL` is an assembler pseudo instruction that puts the value of memory at the address `SYMBOL` into `t0`.  Depending on the addressing mode, it expands to something like

```
lui t0, SYMBOL[31:12]
lw  t0, SYMBOL[11:0](t0)
```

Specifically the difference is that `lw` performs a load from memory, while `la` just generates an address. The sequence

```
la t0, SYMBOL
lw t0, 0(t0) # load word from memory address 0(t0)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
lw t0, SYMBOL
```

but takes an extra instruction, specifically

```
lui t0, SYMBOL[31:12]
addi t0, t0, SYMBOL[11:0]
lw t0, 0(t0)
```

vs

```
lui t0, SYMBOL[31:12]
lw t0, SYMBOL[11:0](t0)
```

This should all be documentation in the [RISC-V Assembly Programmer's Manual](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md), but that is always a work in progress.  If you find that's lacking then feel free to submit a patch or open an issue.

Answer (score 3):

`la` computes an pointer-sized effective address, but does not perform any memory access.  The effective address itself is what is loaded into x7.

(Also note that `la` is a pseudo instruction that may expand into two instructions, depending on `VAL` — none the less, the sequence computes an effective address and that is its result (no memory access is performed).)

`lw` also computes an effective address; however, it uses the effective address in a word-sized memory access, and the result of that memory access is the value loaded into x4.

`lb` would do the same as `lw` except that the memory access is byte-sized.

---

As far as your code sequence goes, the value that was in `x3` (which cannot be determined from your code snippet) will be stored into memory at locations 0x100-0x103 (this is a word-sized store).

The `lw` will reload the value that was written by the `sw`.  (Note that the `lw` in this case may also expand to multiple instructions depending on `VAL`, whereas the `sw` is a single instruction regardless of `VAL`.)

The `bne` (though missing a target label) will not branch.

Answer (score 2):

la instruction  is a pseudoinstruction, it gets the address of the symbol. In specifications, it means:

[image: la]

From: Specifications Volume 1, Unprivileged Spec v. 20191213
(https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/)

The la will be different according the symbol:

1. When the symbol in la is non-PIC(non Position Independent Code), the la will be resolved as auipc and addi.
2. When the symbol is PIC(Position Independent Code), the la will be resolved as auipc and l{w|d}. The symbol will be extend as GOT[symbol], the GOT means: Global Offset Table. And the RV32I use the lw, the RV64I use the ld.

The lw instruction loads a 32-bit value from memory into rd.

So, it is not only a simple 'address' vs 'value' problem, but also depends on the platform and symbol. Because the la will be resolved as different instructions on different situations.